# Difference between coordinator node and the contact point of C++ driver in Cassandra?

Tags: c++, cassandra, cassandra-3.0

When using C++ driver to create APIs for interacting with Cassandra, the C++ program has to be provided a comma separated list, which contains the IP addresses of the nodes which the driver can use as the contact point(cass_cluster_set_contact_points) to the database. I wanted to understand the role of this contact point and if it plays a different role than the coordinator node i.e. is the contact point and the coordinator node one and the same thing.

Also when we are executing, say, a multi-threaded program, for executing several queries, is the coordinator node/contact-point selected for each query or is it just selected at the beginning and then that node is fixed as the coordinator node throughout the execution of the program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The contact endpoints simply serve as a way for your driver to discover the cluster.  You really only need to provide two or three, and the driver will figure out the remaining endpoints via gossip.

When you connect, it is a good idea is to use the `TokenAwareLoadBalancingPolicy`.  That will cause any query filtering on a partition key to bypass the need for a coordinator node, and route directly to the node which is responsible for the required data.

If a query is not filtering on a partition key, or if it is a multi-key query, then an exact node cannot be determined.  At that point, your backup load balancing policy (the `TokenAwareLoadBalancingPolicy` takes a backup policy as an argument) will be used to determine a coordinator node.  If I remember right the `DCAwareRoundRobinLoadBalancingPolicy` is the default.

In summary, the connection endpoints only serve for cluster discovery.  The coordinator node is chosen at query-time, based on algorithms used in your load balancing policy.

Comment: In c++ driver, by default, both token-aware and dc-aware policies are enabled. Since you explained, that in token-aware policy, the coordinator node is bypassed, I wanted to understand how(when dc-aware is also enabled) is the local dc chosen for any query?

Comment: @VishalSharma DCAwareRoundRobin (or whichever backup policy you choose to use with TokenAware) is used when a token cannot be determined.  So if you're using a secondary index query or an unbound query (both anti-patterns) then the DCAwareRoundRobin will be used.

Answer (score 0):

The contact points, which are mentioned in the program are used by the cluster connection setup. The gossip will fetch the entire cluster connection setup based on those ip addresses. The gossip will maintain the ip addresses and other properties of the node and it will always looks whether there is change in the setup and will update everytime if the configuration changes.

If a write or read request happens on ip1, with cluster connected to hosts as ip1, ip2 & ip3, then ip1 is the co-ordinator for this particular operation. It acts as a proxy to process the operation, and redirects the operation to the respective node,say ip4 which is in the cluster but not in the contact list, based on different properties, how the cluster is set up and policies like TokenAwareLoadBalancingPolicy. You can have a look at this article by datastax : https://docs.datastax.com/en/archived/cassandra/1.2/cassandra/architecture/architectureClientRequestsAbout_c.html